# Unable to access Contactshare records in test class as customer community plus portal user

Tags: apex, unit-test, apex-sharing

Our contact OWD is Private

When we convert an existing contact as a customer community plus user, he gets read only access to his own contact with the sharing reason 'Associated Portal User or Role '(created by salesforce behind the scenes).
We found this by clicking share button for the contact.

When we run the below code in test class and try to check for contactshare records we dont see any records(the line before stop test.)

```
@istest
    public static void testmethod1(){
        test.startTest();
        Set<String> customerUserTypes = new Set<String> {'PowerCustomerSuccess'};
            Account acc = new Account (Name = 'newAcc1',recordtypeid = ISD_sObjectUtils.getRecordTypeIdByDeveloperName(Account.sObjectType, 'Business_Account'));  
        insert acc;
        Contact con = new Contact (
            AccountId = acc.id,
            LastName = 'portalTestUser',
            recordtypeid = ISD_sObjectUtils.getRecordTypeIdByDeveloperName(Contact.sObjectType, 'Business_User')
        );
        insert con;
        Profile p = [select Id,name from Profile where UserType in :customerUserTypes limit 1];
        User newUser = new User(
            profileId = p.id,
            username = 'newUser@yahoo.com',
            email = 'pb@ff.com',
            emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8',
            localesidkey = 'en_US',
            languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
            timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            alias='nuser',
            lastname='lastname',
            contactId = con.id
        );
        insert newUser;
        system.debug('newUser' + newUser);
        List<ContactShare> oTemp = [Select Id,ContactAccessLevel, UserOrGroupId from ContactShare where ContactId =:con.Id ];
        system.debug('oTemp-->'+oTemp); 
        test.stopTest();
    }
```

**Questions:**

1. Are we missing anything in our test class code which is causing this behavior?

2.Is this the default behavior in test classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest as follows

Insert the user, and `runas` the particular User, and then you should see at least one record with sharing reason as 'Owner', with the Owner being the `newUser`.

```
@istest
public static void testmethod1(){
    test.startTest();
    User newUser = new User(
            profileId = p.id,
            username = 'newUser@yahoo.com',
            email = 'pb@ff.com',
            emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8',
            localesidkey = 'en_US',
            languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
            timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            alias='nuser',
            lastname='lastname',
            contactId = con.id
        );
    insert newUser;
    System.runAs(newUser){
        Set<String> customerUserTypes = new Set<String> {'PowerCustomerSuccess'};
            Account acc = new Account (Name = 'newAcc1',recordtypeid = ISD_sObjectUtils.getRecordTypeIdByDeveloperName(Account.sObjectType, 'Business_Account'));  
        insert acc;
        Contact con = new Contact (
            AccountId = acc.id,
            LastName = 'portalTestUser',
            recordtypeid = ISD_sObjectUtils.getRecordTypeIdByDeveloperName(Contact.sObjectType, 'Business_User')
        );
        insert con;
        Profile p = [select Id,name from Profile where UserType in :customerUserTypes limit 1];
        List<ContactShare> oTemp = [Select Id,ContactAccessLevel, UserOrGroupId from ContactShare where ContactId =:con.Id ];
        system.debug('oTemp-->'+oTemp); 
    }
    test.stopTest();
}
```